# How do I check if a file/content has a garbled character?

Tags: java, html

I have got a problem with a filter that converts certain character of my uploaded html content to garbled ones. It happened while upgrading to the latest version of that filter.

I would like to add a unit test case to check whether the filtered content has got any garbled character.

I googled through for a solution. I could not find one.

Is there a way?

Comment: @Biffen The Original content was "備 考 test" and the output was "蛯�閠�test". I meant the strange character � as garbled.

Comment: @John once your filler converts to some special characters, what you do next, how you consume that converted text

Comment: @ankur-singhal I am converting the filtered html content to a pdf.

Comment: @John how you are getting this filtered html, possible to show some more code

Comment: We have a framework that filters out the potential xss contents. We faced an issue in the framework code that generated these garbled characters. Rather than the generator, I would want to stop my code from adopting any new framework change with this kind of a bug. I would want to know if there is any way to read through the content and find out the existence of any such garbled character.

Answer (score 1):

In x there is the "garbled" character, which isn't garbled: it is U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER character, to be used by SW if it can't decode some UTF-8 (or any other) encoding. To check, use something like this:

```
String x = "蛯" + (char)0xFFFD + "閠test";
System.out.println( "cpc=" + x.codePointCount(0,x.length()) );
for( int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i ){
    if( (int)x.codePointAt(i) == 0xfffD ){
    System.out.println( "oops" );
    } else {
    System.out.println( x.codePointAt(i) );
    }
}
```

All the usual String test methods work:

```
String gc = "" + (char)0xfffD;
if( x.contains( gc ) ){
    System.out.println( "contains" );
}
if( x.matches( ".*"+gc+".*" ) ){
    System.out.println( "matches" );
}
if( x.indexOf( gc ) > -1 ){
    System.out.println( "indexOf" );
}
```

Even this would do if you are on some Unix system:

```
grep '�' garbled.data
```

Comment: Thanks. So I would have to read through the filtered content for any Unicode code point 0xfffD and decide based on this.

Comment: Just tried a few variations. Any way you deem best.

Comment: But when I run the code on the text "Test�1�Test", It prints the unicode for � as \u00d4 \u00f8 \u03a9 . Something strange? Using this code String.format("\\u%04x", (int) testString.charAt(i))

Comment: The correct UTF-8 encoding for \uFFFD should be 0xef 0xbf 0xbd.